# jQuery get a change of div height after load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I scroll, I need the `#sidebar` fixed between header and footer, to do that i have this code that works works well.

The problem is when in the `#content` there are `div` with `display:none` that they will be showed activating some radio buttons, in that case the `#content` height change, but the code followed doesn't get this change.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var length = $('#content').height() - $('#sidebar').height() + $('#content').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scroller = $(this).scrollTop();
        var height = $('#sidebar').height() + 'px';
        if (scroller < $('#content').offset().top) {
            $('#sidebar').css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                    'top': '0'
            });
        } else if (scroller > length) {
            $('#sidebar').css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                    'bottom': '0',
                    'top': 'auto'
            });
        } else {
            $('#sidebar').css({
                'position': 'fixed',
                    'top': '0',
                    'height': height
            });
        }
    });
});
```

How can i get the `#content` height change after load?

Comment: Hey, try adding a timeout of 500 ms before changing the height.

Comment: When do those radios get checked?

Comment: those radio buttons are selected by the user, and the page don't reload after that!

Comment: Then you need to reassign the value of `var length` when user interacts with radios!

Comment: Isn't there an equivalent of `.change` for the height?